# Bluebird promisifyAll and Node's "oauth" library, callback function expected

Tags: node.js, oauth, promise, bluebird

Trying to use Bluebird promisifyAll to wrap [`oauth`](https://github.com/ciaranj/node-oauth)'s methods, like so:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird')
const OAuth = Promise.promisifyAll(require('oauth'), {
  multiArgs: true
}).OAuth
```

And use like so:

```
const result = await this.oauth.getOAuthAccessTokenAsync(
        // token,
        // tokenSecret,
        // verifier
)
```

(commented out arguments to force an error)

However, instead of falling through to the `catch` block of the surrounding try/catch, my app crashes with (from within the oauth lib):

```
if( error ) callback(error);
                     ^

TypeError: callback is not a function
```

Is there anything else I need to do, to handle errors correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to *promisify* not `oauth` module, but the object created with `new OAuth.OAuth()`:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird')
const OAuth = require('oauth').OAuth;

var oauth = new OAuth();

Promise.promisifyAll(oauth, { multiArgs: true });
```

**Update:**

Or you can *promisify* `OAuth.prototype`, as *Ben Fortune* suggested:

```
Promise.promisifyAll(OAuth.prototype, { multiArgs: true });
```

[Working example](https://gist.github.com/AlexanderMac/4c04f0eb9957994a30a7e7f75ca70051)

Comment: Strange, trying both of the ways above yields the same error :/

Comment: Strange, for me it works well. What versions of oAuth and Bluebird do you use?

Comment: `"bluebird": "^3.5.0", "oauth": "^0.9.15"` - I've reverted to manually wrapping each call in a Promise :(

Comment: I don't know why this code doesn't work for you, please try the complete [demo](https://gist.github.com/AlexanderMac/4c04f0eb9957994a30a7e7f75ca70051)